# how to get residuals and perform the Durbin Watson test on Rolling Linear regression?

Tags: r

i have run this below coded for which I got the result of coefficients and r2 values,

```
model <- roll_regres(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, Data, width = 15L, do_downdates = FALSE, do_compute = c("sigmas", "r.squareds"))

coef <- outneg$coefs

r2 <- outneg$r.squareds
```

and what I need is to do the Durban-Watson test on residuals? the problem here is I am not able to extract the residuals from `roll_regres`. how do I get the residual values for rolling window regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the residuals of each of the expanding length window regression model? You can get them like this.

```
residuals = lapply(15:nrow(Data), function(x) {
  lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = Data[1:x,])$residuals
})
```

Comment: thanks, @langtang, yet I need to get coefficients too and r2 too.  can I use roll regress for coefs and r2 and lappy for residuals? or is there any way I can get them in a single function

Comment: looks like you figured it out in another question. make sure you select and upvote the answer(s) that are helpful